# Specular over texture in OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, lighting

I'm trying to get specular highlight over objetcs that are texture mapped. As far as I know, the only direct way for OpenGL to not compute the final color over the texture color (this is, as for example plain white) is with the call `glLightModelf(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL,GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR)`, but that is not supported in OpenGL ES.

So, how can I do this? Do I have to use another texture for the specluar highlight, of is there another easier way?

Than you!

P.S. I'm using OpenGL ES 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround would be to run in two passes: first pass renders the texture with ambient & diffuse lighting, the second pass renders the specular highlights on top of that (without texturing enabled).

Comment: +1 Of course in this case you should use additive blending (`glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)`) and a depth test with `glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL)`.

Comment: It seems like the correct way, but I can't make it to work perfect. With the blending function `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)` the entire object appears very bright (the light is white), maybe with othe blending function will work better, but I can't figure out which one

Comment: Ok, my bad, I forgot to change the material for the untextured object to 0 ambient and 0 diffuse, so only the specular highlight is colored. It works now! thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the great suggestions, they saved my day. The only problem was a flicker. I first thought there was a problem with a depth buffer and limited depth resolution but it was not the case. I had to use gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_ALWAYS); for perfect blending. However for complex primitives you will be able to see through the object.

After playing for another week I figured that one simply has to disable depth test when doing blending and simply take care of the order in which you render objects on each pass. Typically you want to finish all rendering passes for far object before drawing a closer one. 
This takes care for flicker problem that I had completely.